# Excel VBA Dictionary Removing Items

Tags: vba, excel

I have the problem that calling the Remove-Method on the Scripting.Dictionary-Object won't work.

```
Dim temp As String
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

dict .Add(2,"asd")
dict .Add(3,"asd")
dict .Add(4,"asd")
dict .Add(5,"asd")
dict .Add(6,"asd")

For Each Key in dict.Keys
   temp = Key
   If(Key > 3) Then
       dict.Remove(temp)
   End If
Next
```

Running this code yields the same number of items in the dictionary for me.

Edit: I just modified the code to better reflect the actual usage. As it turns out the string conversion is at fault here. After casting the key to a string the dictionary can't match the values correctly. Unfortunately this hasn't helped me in getting a solution for the problem.

Edit2: The Key object itself is of type Range. Assigning it to a string variable leads to the problem, that the comparison fails on the remove operation. I tried using variants as an alterantive but the Key is cast to string nevertheless.

Comment: Doesn't work. I should note that i don't get an error message. The relevant entries are simply not removed.

Comment: Dont use paranthesis in Remove

Answer (score 3):

```
Sub x()

Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim i As Variant

Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary

dict.Add 2, "asd"
dict.Add 3, "asd"
dict.Add 4, "asd"
dict.Add 5, "asd"
dict.Add 6, "asd"

For Each i In dict.Keys()
    if i>3 then dict.Remove i
Next i


End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

The key is the second parameter ("asd"), not the number, so you aren't actually removing anything. Reversing the order of the parameters  when you add itsms should work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's Key, Value: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h92h863%28v=vs.84%29.aspx

Comment: Ooooops! You are quite right. My apologies Another, hopefully better thought: Isn't your key a string type, so even though you are adding it as a number it's being converted? I suspect that might be making your comparison fail ( "3">3 )

Comment: The code above is just an example. My actual code used strings as the key. Furthermore the key is saved in a string variable in a side step, which is apparently the cause of the mismatch.